# How to get size of the object in kilobyte(kb) or in byte

Tags: java, android, object, size

In my android application, it collect some data and photo throw mobile.

After that it insert all these things into an object and after that it send this object to the server.

Before sending this object onto server I want to show the size of the data to the user and how many killobyte used to send this data to the server.
Here I am using **progressBar** which show only data is sending to the server.

Here what I want, before sending data to server first it show what is the size of data and after starting progressBar how may data transferred and how many renaming.

I am sending object like this:

```
public class ServerData implements Serializable {
// some code
}
```

Comment: How are you sending the object? As a string, serialized, json, ... ?

Comment: You can quite easily obtain the size of a file; however, this does not tell the number of bytes which will actually be exchanged along the wire: TCP overhead etc.

Comment: the object is Serializable....

Comment: but in lot of application I have seen they show how may data transfer from mobile to there server

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that, is to write it to a buffer-stream, find its size then write it to your server as byte array.

```
       ByteArrayOutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
           try {
              ObjectOutputStream obStream = new ObjectOutputStream(ostream);
              obStream.writeObject(yourObject);
              byte[] rawObject = ostream.toByteArray();
              ostream.close();

              int size = rawObject.length;
             //edit for your case
             OutputStream socketOut = socket.getOutputStream();
             socketOut.write(rawObject);
             socketOut.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @Mr.Me... thanx... but if I give object of ByteArrayOutputStream in ObjectOutputStream then how I give socket.getOutputStream().
My code is: ObjectOutputStream  obStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

but as by your code: ObjectOutputStream obStream = new ObjectOutputStream(ostream);

Then where I give socket.getOutputStream().